# Replacement 1970s house siding

Tags: siding

Our house was built in the 70s, and has some siding that needs to be repaired. The siding, which is original, seems to have come in 4x8 sheets, is a compressed fiber board material, white, with dimples, somewhat like a golf ball.

It is about a quarter of an inch thick, so it's not that thin plastic stuff.

Close up of white siding panels.  Hard to tell, but these are dimples.  Somewhat like a golf ball.
[image]

From farther back.
[image]

Another shot of the siding.
[image]

Can anyone tell me what it's called?

Comment: You *might* want to send a sample from one of the damaged boards to a lab for an asbestos check. I don't recognize that particular pattern, but the era is right for asbestos still being "a miracle product of insulation and fire protection" rather than "oh, and it can give you cancer" being a consideration, yet.

Comment: Now you got me bummed out.   But maybe if I add asbestos to my google, I'll find it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just something to check - may not be. It could well be any number of non-asbestos products, though. But without testing, you can't tell by looking at it unless it has a handy legible trademark of an asbestos product maker on it... If you pop a sheet off and it says Transite® on the back, then no need for a lab test. It's largely innocuous if left alone - turning it to dust is where you have to be cautious with it.

Comment: I embedded the pics for you to save everyone time, and I removed the "where to buy it" because that's a shopping question and explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you FreeMan.  I'm new to this forum.  Just knowing what it is or the manufacturer would get me a long way there.